# In what situation are a PHP session handler class methods called statically?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I have a custom session handler class which stores sessions in a database. When writing data, there is some custom logic which handles the write a bit differently based on whether or not it is creating a new session or updating an existing one. To track this, the class property `existingSession` is set when the session is first read.

The code (cut down for brevity) is as follows:

```
class My_Session_SaveHandler implements Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface
{
    protected $existingSession;

    public function read($id)
    {
        if ($id) {
            $this->existingSession = (load existing data from db)
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        if ($this->existingSession) { 
            [update session]
        } else {
            [create session]
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

this all seems to work fine. However I sometimes see errors like this in the logs:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: My_Session_SaveHandler::$existingSession in /path/to/My/Session/SaveHandler.php on line xxx,

Since `$existingSession` is a declared property, the only thing I could think that would cause this is if the write method is being called statically. I could modify the variable to be a static property instead, but since the class seems to work, I'd like to understand whether session handler class methods are always called statically, or whether it just happens sometimes (and if so why).

**Edit**: the line number in the notice is the line of the `if ($this->existingSession) {` check in the write function.

Comment: Can you paste the code from the line XXX indicated in the PHP Notice?

Comment: The notice is generated by the `if ($this->existingSession) {` at the start of the write function.

Comment: Is this the whole class definition? Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface requires the methods `destroy`,`gc`, `open` and `close`, which aren't shown here. It may help to resolve this issue if we can see all of the code for this class.

Comment: The full class is 200 lines so I cut quite a lot of it out to keep the question short. I don't think the other methods are relevant to this issue - `open()`, `close()` and `gc()` do nothing; `destroy()` just deletes the session from the db

Comment: One possible scenario is the `write` function is being called before `$this->existingSession` is initialized. If you want to understand when it's being called add a new condition `if (empty($this->existingSessions)) Zend_Debug::dump(debug_backtrace());` and check the application stack. BTW, adding empty() to your condition would make the warning go away, but you wouldn't know when this is happening.

Comment: Thanks, empty() would fix it as well, I guess I'm just trying to understand the cause. Even if `write` was being called first for some reason would that throw a notice, as the property it's complaining about is declared at the top of the class.

Comment: The method is not called statically, that would make it fail with a *"cannot use `$this` in non-object context"* error.

Comment: My immediate assumption was the same as Rolando's (that the property had not had a value set to it), but from testing, I've not been able to generate a notice from this. When a new object is created, any properties that are defined without a value as shown in the code are set to null until a value is set to them